# Общеславянский или праславянский?

Tags: языкознание

В словаре Черных обычно дается пометка:  о.-с. основа, и.-е. корень. Однако в предисловии  от издательства сказано, что употребление термина "общеславянский" для определения праславянских слов является "досадным анахронизмом". Так ли это?

И есть ли разница между этими терминами? Считается, что письменных памятников общеславянского периода не сохранилось, и тогда общеславянский/праславянский язык - это в любом случае язык реконструированный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vera, я дилетант в этом вопросе (как, признаться, и во всех остальных), но навскидку это терминологический спор, почти абсолютно бессодержательный, как и всякий терминологический.

Насколько понимаю, под этими двумя терминами понимают одну и ту же языковую общность, существовавшую предположительно с начала тысячелетия (устанавливается по факту первых более или менее достоверных сведений о славянах) до V-VI века. Окончательно исчез не позднее VII.

Вот из вики каcательно термина:

> Также некоторыми исследователями для обозначения праславянского языка применяется синонимичный термин «общеславянский язык» (фр. slave commune, англ. Common Slavic, нем. Gemeinslavisch, хорв. općeslavenski)[17][18] или «славянский язык-основа»[19].

Фраза о "досадном анахронизме" мной воспринимается так, что сам термин показался автору неудачным. И это можно отчасти понять, поскольку под "общеславянским" (словом, морфом) понимается современный срез лексики, присутствующий во всех (или большинстве) славянских языков всех современных групп. Кого-то это может путать.

> Считается, что письменных памятников общеславянского периода не сохранилось, и тогда общеславянский/праславянский язык - это в любом случае язык реконструированный.

Безусловно так. Даже если предположить достоверность интерпретации сведений о т.н. "чертах и резах" как о реальной славянской письменности (что в общем-то отвергается большинством ученых), то это никак не ранее VII-VIII века, т.е. в лучшем случае период окончательного распада праславянской языковой общности.
Более того, достоверных полных реконструкций не существует. Тут проблема в том, что не ясна схема распада (т.е. что от чего и в какой последовательности отделялось), а, следовательно, не ясен и общий "ствол", по которому устанавливается, какие морфы более древние (других адекватных способов установить это, вроде, и не существует).
Например такой момент, существовал ли т.н. "протославянский" язык - как предок праславянского, или же праслявянский непосредственный потомок (пра-)балтославяснкого.
Или то, распалась праславянская общность одновременно на три современные группы или же первое деление было на западнославянский и юговосточнославянский. Все это ключевые моменты для полной реконструкции. Тем не менее, при всех различиях, варианты полной реконструкции совпадают по меньшей мере наполовину, что в общем-то дает представление о языке.

Для полноты картины о сущности терминов можете заглянуть на специализированные ресурсы, например сюда
 [Праславянский язык | slawianie.narod.ru](http://slawianie.narod.ru/str/jazyk/prasl.html)
Но предупреждаю, сайт не вызывает у меня полного доверия по части исторических сведений и терминологии, пользуйте просто как информацию о том, что такое мнение есть. (А сама реконструкция представлена неплохо).

Comment: Большое спасибо за материал, обязательно ознакомлюсь с ним подробнее.